# MongoDB query returning inconsistent results with mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm encountering an issue with a Python script that utilizes mongoengine to query MongoDB.

When executing the same query multiple times, it returns the expected data some of the times, while other times it returns **no data** at all from the collection.

Sample code:

```py
class Employee(Document):
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    department: str = StringField()
    employeeName: str = StringField()
    createdAt: int = LongField()
    meta = {
        'strict': False,
        'collection': 'employee'
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unique_names = Employee.objects(group="foo").distinct("employeeName")
    print(len(unique_names))

    cursor1 = Employee.objects(employeeName="john")
    print(len(list(cursor1)))
```

With the data being unchanged in the DB, **sometimes** the 2 queries are returning empty data, as if there are no records in Employee collection.

I could not see any pattern as to when it is failing. Out of 100 invocations, it sometimes fails 2-3 times where as somtimes it fails 70-80% of the time!

Please note -

- This scrip is running in AWS Lambda + APIGateway setup.
- MongoDB version - 5.0.25
- mongoengine - 0.24.2
- Python 3.9

Comment: Do you get similar results if you query via mongo shell?

Comment: @MichaelRuth Thanks, I will test this today, although the behaviour is hard to reproduce and very inconsistent.